# How to create List from Range

Tags: algorithm, scala

I am new to Scala, just started learning, so this is basic beginner question.

I try to implement [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) algorithm. Here is what I got so far:

```
def sieve_core(cross: Int, lst: Seq[Int]): List[Int] = {
    val crossed = lst.filter(_ % cross != 0)
    crossed match {
            case a :: rest => cross :: sieve_core(a, crossed)
            case _ => cross :: Nil
    }
}

def sieve(max: Int): List[Int] = {
    sieve_core(2, (2 to max))
}

println(sieve(100))
```

The result is:

```
List(2)
```

As far as I understand, `case _ => cross :: Nil` is matched in first iteration of `sieve_core`, which means that `crossed` is not an instance of a List.

I changed `lst` parameters type to `List[Int]` and now the code won't compile with an error:

```
(fragment of Problem3.scala):24: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Range.Inclusive
 required: List[Int]
    sieve_core(2, (2 to max))
                      ^
```

Apparently `Range` is not a `List`.

Question: how can I turn Range into a List? Or is it some bigger problem with my code, I have made some bad assumption somewhere along the way?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There's an `apply` method on the `List` companion object which takes a range and returns a `List`:

```
scala> List.range(2, 11)
res0: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

There are lots of useful `List` factory methods [in the `List` collection documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List$).

Comment: I checked List class apidocs, haven't checked List object docs. Now I know better. Thanks.

Comment: You know, it's super annoying how they aren't prominently linked to each other, or even combined into a single page :)

Comment: This is supposed to be deprecated, I'm told. `2 to max toList` will work.

Comment: Thanks, I revised the answer. 2.7.3 docs released in January 2009 gave no hint...

Comment: caution: the very nice option of dropping the "." may still require you to add parens later for methods with no arguments: 2 to 4 toList reverse parses as `.toList(reverse)`, so you need `(2 to 4 toList) reverse` or `(2 to 4).toList reverse` or more conventionally, `2.to(4).toList.reverse` - but I still drop the ".()" if I can.

Answer (score 7):

To turn any sequence `s` into a list, use `s.toList`

I'm sure digitalross' is more efficient in this case, though.

Answer (score 0):

`(2 to max)` is not a [scala.collection.immutable.List](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.0/scala/collection/immutable/List.html) indeed but a [scala.collection.immutable.Range](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.0/scala/collection/immutable/Range.html), more precisely an instance of `scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive`, as mentioned in your error message. Just in passing note that `Inclusive` and `Exclusive` are themselves members of `Range`, with a fairly auto-explanatory meaning.

Luckily the Range class offers the handy method `toList`, which you can leverage for converting the range into a list and resolve the problem, like in the following code snippet:

```
scala> val max = 10
max: Int = 10

scala> val r = (2 to max)
r: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range 2 to 10

scala> val l = r.toList
l: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```